# SetTimeout javascript countdown Timer with delay

Tags: javascript, jquery, settimeout, countdowntimer, jquery-events

hi i am confused with the below code

JSfiddle [link](http://jsfiddle.net/KJTjc/)

```
for (var i=6;i>=0;i--)
    {
       
        setTimeout((function(i)
              {
                  
            $("div").delay(4000).html(i);
            alert(i); //if commented unable to see the countdown
            
              })
            (i),4000);
        //alert(1);
        
    }
```

I am not able to get the count down timer.. whats wrong.. when "alert" is commented unable to see the count down numbers.
Please somebody explain how the above code works.. Post some correct code

Comment: ITYM "can please somebody explain why the code above _doesn't_ work"...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. `.delay()` only works for jQuery animation methods, not general jQuery methods such as `.html()`
2. All of your timeouts are getting fired at once - there's nothing to space them out.

The net result is that (without an `alert`) every iteration through the loop runs immediately, leaving the `div` containing `0` having invisibly (and very briefly) contained the other numbers from the previous iterations.

Try this, instead:

```
function counter($el, n) {
    (function loop() {
       $el.html(n);
       if (n--) {
           setTimeout(loop, 1000);
       }
    })();
}

counter($('div'), 6);
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/t3AA8/

Comment: yes i do agree with that.. delay is not my concern here.. but in my question above when i have alert it works fine.. when i comment it out it goes crazy.. how is the execution happening..

Comment: the `alert` is most likely just given the system time to process the timeout events.  You should use `console.log` for debugging instead of `alert`.

Comment: ok i used console.log instead of alert.. i am getting all the numbers 6 to 0 in the log. But i am not able to see the same in the div tag  using delay and timeout. Kindly check the code yourself on JSfiddle and explain how the things are getting fired.. thank you..

Comment: like I told you, `.delay()` doesn't work on most jQuery methods.  You call that code from `6..0` and without the `alert` _nothing_ stops it from immediately reaching the `0` iteration and overwriting the div with that value.  Did you even try my code?

Comment: yes i tried it and used it in my program . thank you for that.. as per my knowledge javascript execution doesnt happen sequentially...

Comment: @Nirus actually _everything_ happens sequentially.  The exception is that things like `setTimeout` cause functions to be added to a queue, and when the browser isn't busy processing your code it removes functions from that queue and executes them.  It's all pretty deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

Do not use alert, because alert will stop everything. Use `console.log`